# SQL Dynamic Pivot query involving FOR XML PATH TYPE VALUE not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have searched everywhere and I think it is probably just some little thing I am not seeing or don't know about since this is my first adventure in dynamic pivot queries. I'm using SQL Server 2012. I found examples of what I needed my data to do and I was able to get the example to work. I tried to adapt that to my data and I started getting errors.

I'm getting a Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near '('.

I searched for solutions to the Msg 102 error and have tried the suggestions that were applicable, but I still get the error. I tried to split up the lines to see if I could narrow down where the actual error was and it actually seems to maybe indicate it is the ('') after the FOR XML PATH. And, so I searched for syntax for that. No luck finding a solution that works. I've been trying to fix this for a day and now I'm gonna cry uncle. Here is what I have with some sample data below. (I do not have the SF_DocID field involved yet, because I was trying to get the pivot part to work first, but what I'd really like to do is group by the SF_DocID too.)

```
USE X_Projects
GO

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Contact_prompt)
                    FROM dbo.dcm_Q2a1
                FOR XML PATH
                ('')
                , 
                TYPE)
                .value
                (
                '.'
                ,
                 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                 ,1,1,'')

SELECT @query =
'SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
    Contact_prompt,
    Contact_lookup_name
FROM dbo.dcm_Q2a1)X
PIVOT
(
    SUM(ISNULL(CAST(Contact_lookup_name AS FLOAT),0))
    for Contact_prompt in (' + @cols +')
) P'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query

dbo.dcm_Q2a1
SF_DocID Contact_prompt        Contact_lookup_name
1        Contact               Phone
1        Contactor             Provider/Billing
1        Current Eligibility   Eligible
1        Line of Business      Exchange
1        Member Language       English
2        Contact               Phone
2        Contactor             Provider/Billing
2        Current Eligibility   Eligible
2        Line of Business      Exchange
2        Member Language       English
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

**RESULTS**:
I'm aiming for (and I'd want it to show `"NULL"` in any blank spaces):

```
SF_DocID Contact Contactor  Current Eligibility  Line of Business etc.
1        Phone   Provider/B Eligible             Exchange         etc.
2        Phone   Provider/B Eligible             Exchange         etc.
etc.
etc.
```

The number of Contact_prompt data values can vary so I need dynamic columns. (Also, I can't change the data values as they already exist, but I'm a little concerned about the ones that have the word "Current" and "of" in them. Is that going to trip up things? I'm hoping not since I shouldn't have to list them since it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
SUM(ISNULL(CAST(Contact_lookup_name AS FLOAT),0))
```

not sure where you copied that from, but your field is `varchar(16)` so you should use MIN or MAX

```
SELECT  @cols = STUFF((SELECT   ',' + QUOTENAME (Contact_prompt) 
                        FROM    dbo.dcm_Q2a1 
                        GROUP BY Contact_prompt -- distinct
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1,'')
SET @query = '
    SELECT  [SF_DocID],'
            + @cols + '
    FROM    dcm_Q2a1
    PIVOT   (
        MAX([Contact_lookup_name])
        FOR [Contact_prompt] IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) p
'
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a few syntax errors, and your key key cols where not distinct

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Contact_prompt) FROM (Select Distinct Contact_prompt from dbo.dcm_Q2a1) A FOR XML PATH ('') , TYPE) .value ( '.' , 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 
SELECT @query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT SF_DocID,Contact_prompt, Contact_lookup_name FROM dbo.dcm_Q2a1)X PIVOT ( max(Contact_lookup_name) for Contact_prompt in (' + @cols +') ) P'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Returns

```
SF_DocID    Contact Contactor   Current Eligibility Line of Business    Member Language
1   Phone   Provider/Billing    Eligible            Exchange            English
2   Phone   Provider/Billing    Eligible            Exchange            English
3   Phone   NULL                NULL                NULL                NULL
```